# NameError in Controller#new in view in ruby on rails on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am currently doing a CRUD, i am now in part of create method but I'm encountering when I load the new method(this is where my form is) NameError in Products#new

Question: Is my products_create_path correct? This is the action after I send the form into create method

**New file**

```
Add New Item

<%= form_for :product, url: products_create_path do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :Name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :Size %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :Price %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :price %>

    </p>x   
    <p>
    <%= f.submit :Submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'BACK', products_path %>
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 resources :products
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

**Controller**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @product = Product.all.order('created_at DESC')

  end
  def show
    @post = Product.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end
  def create
    @post = Product.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
    redirect_to (products_path)
    else
    redirect_to('new')
    end
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name, :size, :price)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to give `url` in form_for tag. Rails internally redirect to path depends on in presence of id value.

Change form_for tag to this:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
```

So in your form_for tag, object (@product) has value for id field, then rails will submit the form to update routes else it will submit the form to create routes.

Comment: check out this for more details : https://railscodders.wordpress.com/difference-between-form_for-and-form_tag%C2%A0/

Comment: Sir I have another question, If i am in delet method, what should I put to link_to? Like this?<%= link_to 'Delete', delete_product_path(p) %>

Comment: use this <%= link_to "Delete", delete_product_path(p), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>

Answer (score 1):

In your form change `:description` to `:size`

and change

```
<%= form_for :product, url: products_create_path do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

change your form_tag to

```
<%= form_for @post, :url => new_product_path do |f| %>
```

or

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
```

Comment: Last question sir, after I submitted the form it gives me another error " Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/products/new" " But in my routes i declared it as resources.. Why sir

Answer (score 1):

products_create_path is not correct and you don't need it either. Your form should be <%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
<%= form_for :product, url: products_path do |f| %>
```

You can check your routes by using this command:

```
rake routes
```

Or find more information from [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

Hope I can help.